# How to globally disable update checks via gpgconf file on Windows?

Tags: windows, gnupg, gpg4win

### What I want to do:

*We deploy gpg4win automatically and need to adjust some options.
Currently I use a startup script to create and edit configuration files below the users %appdata% folder directly.
This is getting tedious.
Yet gpgconf seemed to me needlessly confusing and slow on windows.
Recently I tried to migrate to a cleaner solution, picking up gpgconf again.*

Specifically, I currently try to **disable automatic update checks for all users**.

### What I tried:

```
>gpgconf --list-config
gpgconf: can not open global config file 'C:\ProgramData\GNU\etc\gnupg\gpgconf.conf': No such file or directory
```

This told me where the file *should* be. I still could not find an example file or any documentation on how to populate it. So I copied the [example config](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/matsuu/gnupg/master/doc/examples/gpgconf.conf) for unix systems.

and created **'C:\ProgramData\GNU\etc\gnupg\gpgconf.conf'** with uncommented lines:

```
*       dirmngr allow-version-check [default]
        dirmngr allow-version-check [no-change]
```

yet this gives me:

```
>gpgconf --apply-defaults
gpgconf: option allow-version-check already changed
gpgconf: fatal error (exit status 1)
```

I want allow-version-check to be removed from user profiles when `gpgconf --apply-defaults` is executed.

Thanks to everyone reading/answering this!

Any clever advice on how to do this smoothly without the global gpgconf.conf is welcome, too!

### Documentation used:

[gpgconf docs](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/gpgconf.html), [config locations](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Files-used-by-gpgconf.html#Files-used-by-gpgconf) (does not cover Windows)

[Gpg4win Compendium](https://www.gpg4win.org/doc/en/gpg4win-compendium_28.html) (Old user settings path)

[Example config](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/matsuu/gnupg/master/doc/examples/gpgconf.conf) (Windows specific file where?)

### Env

gpgconf (GnuPG) 2.2.7, Ggp4Win 3.1.1, Win 10 1709

Comment: There's currently also a bug in kleopatra related to update checks: https://dev.gnupg.org/T4043